# How do you make a messageRead indicator by changing a UIView when a row is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm building a messaging app and trying to create a messageRead indicator similar to the blue dot in iMessage. When the user selects a row, I set the UIView.background to clear. However, the cell doesn't update upon returning from the detail view. I feel like I missing something obvious, but can't figure it out.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MessagePreviewCell
    cell.customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set delegate for your tableView?

Comment: I'm using a table view controller. I'm pretty sure the delegate is automatically set to self?

Comment: Yes, for sure. Maybe this view is no last hierarchy?  Also you can try tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

Comment: Wow that worked. I don't understand how didn't come across that function. Thanks a lot.